# Place an object to root level in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a aggregate query that fetches result from 3 collections.

I am using mongoDb 3.4

One Sample doc from result.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba1717ee4b00ce08ca47cfa"),  
    "name" : "captain jack", 
    "email" : "jack@gmail.com", 
    "mobile" : "9000000023", 
    "status" : "verified", 
    "courses" : [
        {
            "_id" : "13", 
            "name" : "Course (03)"
        },{
            "_id" : "12", 
            "name" : "Course (03)"
        }
    ], 
    "examCompleted" : false, 
    "login" : "5ba1717ee4b00fe08ca47cfa", 
    "partnerMetaInfo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ba1717ee4b00fe08ca47cfa"), 
        "costCode" : "5761", 
        "hub" : "CALCUTTA", 
        "location" : "Kolkata" 

    }
}
```

I am trying to bring `partnerMetaInfo` at root level.
I am also unable to filter courses._id using $match on _id == 13

This is my aggregate query :

```
db.getCollection("mainCollection").aggregate([
        {
            //Join two collection
            $lookup:{
                from: "Details",
                localField: "username",
                foreignField: "login",
                as: "partnerData"
            }
        },{
            //Limit fields
            $project:{
                "email":1,
                "name":1,
                "mobile":1,
                "status" : 1,
                "courses":"$partnerData.courses",
                "examScore" : "$partnerData.examScore",
                "examCompleted" : "$partnerData.examCompleted",
                "login":"$partnerData.login"
            }
        },
        {
            //Join third collection
            $lookup:{
                from: "PartnerMetaInfo",
                localField: "login",
                foreignField: "partnerId",
                as: "partnerMetaInfo"
            }
        },
        //Remove from partnerData array and place at root level.
        {
            $unwind:
            {
                path: '$courses',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },{
            $unwind:
            {
                path: '$examScore',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },{
            $unwind:
            {
                path: '$examCompleted',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },{
            $unwind:
            {
                path: '$login',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },//Bring $partnerMetaInfo array to root level.
        {
            $unwind:
            {
                path: '$partnerMetaInfo',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },{
            $limit:10
        }
    ];
```

partnerMetaInfo after $unwind ends up as object. I want to flatten it and bring it at root level.

Can any body help me with this?

Comment: If I understood correctly, `partnerMetaInfo` is already at root level then you can add one more project at the end `$project:{ partnerMetaInfo: 1}` and it will return only `partnerMetaInfo` along with `_id`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you want to get as a result is the content of your `partnerMetaInfo` field then you can simply add a [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) stage at the end of your pipeline like this:

```
{
    $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": { $ifNull: [ "$partnerMetaInfo", {} ] } }
}
```

Otherwise, in case you want to simply move the fields inside the `partnerMetaInfo` field to the root then you would use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/):

```
{
    $addFields: {
        "partnerMetaInfoId" : "$partnerMetaInfo._id", 
        "costCode" : "$partnerMetaInfo.costCode", 
        "hub" : "$partnerMetaInfo.hub", 
        "location" : "$partnerMetaInfo.location" 
    }
}
```

If you have a dynamic number of fields or do not want to hardcode field names then you can use the following logic:

```
{
    $replaceRoot: { // merge fields of and move them all the way up
        "newRoot": { $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT", "$partnerMetaInfo" ] }
    }
}, {
    $project: { // remove the "partnerMetaInfo" field
        "partnerMetaInfo": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives an error stating ```''newRoot' expression must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: MISSING. Type of resulting value: 'missing'.```

I have already used $unwind, so array is converted to an object. Now i need to flatten the object and place it at root. I hope I am clear.

Comment: Well, If I remove ```preserveNullAndEmptyArrays```, then the doc will disappear from the result if partnerMetaInfo is empty or null.

Comment: Try the updated version above. It's still early morning here and I'm a little blind still. ;)

Comment: Doesnt work. returns a lot of empty objects and alters the structure of docs. :(

Comment: @HardikShah : yes the partnerMetaInfo is already at the root level as a object. But i need to remove the fields in the object and place it at root level. Your solution didnt work. Thx anyways.

Comment: the no of keys inside metaInfo will be dynamic. In the sense that some object will have 5 keys , some may need 10 fields. So i cant hardcode. Is there any shorthand for all keys example ```*```